How I can access the hardware register on Jetson Xavier with Python
I am trying to access the hardware register in Python to generate an interruption each 100ms. I know that the timer register for the Jetson Xavier is the **TKE_AON_TIMER_TMR0_TMRCR_0 **, but I need to configure this register to generate an interrupt that is generated every 100ms to read.
Generate an interrupt through the Jetson Xavier register to read the values given by a sensor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First you need to download the Xavier Technical Reference Manual https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=TRM&tx=$product,jetson_agx_xavier
Then you can reference section 8.4.4 to get the register address.
then you can use busybox to try to read from the address. For examples
busybox devmem 0x0243d008
Then you can use that address to read the register from python using project such as https://github.com/kylemanna/pydevmem
